# ERROR: Property 'UnityEngine.Component.constantForce' is read only in Monodevelop Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, terrain

```
function Start () 
{
   var linkedTerrain:Terrain = gameObject.GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[0,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[0,1] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[0,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[1,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[1,1] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[1,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[2,0] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[2,1] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);
  _terrainGrid[2,2] = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(linkedTerrain.terrainData).GetComponent(Terrain);

  _terrainGrid[0,0].transform.constantForce = Vector3(0,0,1.0);  
}
```

I got an error in above line ERROR:Property `UnityEngine.Component.constantForce` is read only

I want to Create Materix of Terrain and Apply ConstantForce on them so they move. I need Materix bacause I wanna reuse them and create EndLess Envirnoment with they are moving.
I tried and got ERROR on this line:

```
_terrainGrid[X,Y].transform.constantForce = Vector3(0,0,1.0);
```

ERROR:

```
Property 'UnityEngine.Component.constantForce' is read only
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ConstantForce.relativeForce = Vector3(0, 0, 1.0);
```

`constantForce.relativeForce` represents the force, relative to the rigid bodies coordinate system, applied to every frame.